# Does RAM affect on Overfitting Neural Network?

Tags: python, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am training a neural network using 11000 images for two classes. Once I trained it using my laptop 4GB RAM and jupyter notbook for 5 epochs, everything was ok. 
I ran my code into google colab with 6GB RAM usage, Now it is overfitting at first epoch?
here is my code

```
def CreateModel():
model = Sequential()

# 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(227,227,3), kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(4,4), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(11,11), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(1,1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2), padding='valid'))

# Passing it to a Fully Connected layer
model.add(Flatten())
# 1st Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(227*227*3,) , kernel_regularizer=l2(0.05), bias_regularizer=l2(0.05)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# 2nd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096 , kernel_regularizer=l2(0.05), bias_regularizer=l2(0.5)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(1000 , kernel_regularizer=l2(0.05), bias_regularizer=l2(0.05)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.5))

# Output Layer
model.add(Dense(2))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()
return model
```

What is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: How can you tell whether a model is overfitting after the first epoch?

Comment: after 2-3 minutes its accuracy reached 100% and in the second epoch it is 100% too, and not changed until the last epoch @MatusDubrava

Comment: RAM consumption shouldn’t have any effect, no, especially since memory use is determined by the program, and not vice-versa.

Comment: 100% accuracy does not mean overfitting, are you even using validation data?